# Find & Replace Specific DIV With jQuery

Tags: jquery

I have a page I am working with that has several hidden DIVs that are identically formatted, but the content within each DIV varies. I want to be able to seek out a specific DIV (based on it's content), unhide it, and replace it with custom content.

For instance, I have:

```
<div class="caption" style="display:none">[ProductDetail_Espot]</div>
```

And I want:

```
<div class="caption" style=""><p>My Custom Content</p></div>
```

I have looked at a couple regex scripts and stuff, but I'm not a genius when it comes to scripting, so any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you know that only one div has this content, then you can use the [`:contains` *<sup>[docs]</sup>*](http://api.jquery.com/contains-selector/) selector:

```
$('.caption:contains("[ProductDetail_Espot]")')
   .html("<p>My Custom Content</p>")
   .show();
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$(function(){
    $(".caption:contains('Espot')).show().html('<p>My custom content</p>');
});
```

demo: 
http://jsfiddle.net/EsPym/1/

Comment: This works, but to clear things up, I have 20+ DIV's with the .caption class. I only want to target the DIV that has "[ProductDetail_Espot]" as it's content.

Answer (score 0):

Some simple jQuery to get you going...

```
$("#caption").show();
```

will show it,

```
$("#caption").html("<p>some html</p>");
```

will replace contents.

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#[ELEMENT ID]").click(function(){
$(".caption").show().html('[YOU NEW ACCONT]');
})
```